# React native : Deleting the right item from ListVIew

Tags: listview, react-native

I'm using React Native (0.29.0) on Android and have a ListView component on my page. I want to be able to remove items from the list.I'm fairly new to react-native.

Here is the ListView Component :

```
<ListView
    key = {items}  //An array of strings(same as the datasource)
    dataSource = {this.state.datasource}
    renderRow = {(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => <Item data={rowData} onPress={this.deleteItem}/>}
/>
```

Here is the method to delete an item:

```
deleteItem(rowData, sectionID, rowID)
{   
    //items.splice(rowID ,1);
    this.setState({datasource: ds.cloneWithRows(items)});
}
```

Tried using rowID to delete an item,it deletes the first element from the list and the list is re-rendered.
Used console.warn to check what was in rowID,says it is "undefined".

I read several similar questions online and they said that i need to use a key, I'm not entirely sure how to use a key.Tried passing in the key to the deleteItem method,again, it says key is "undefined"

I'm finding it difficult to identify which row needs to be deleted from within the deleteItem method.It'll be really helpful if someone can guide me on right path, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments to your onPress method. You use onPress on a element, this element has no idea it's on a list or not. So the component can't pass on any data about it's location in a list.

You need to do:

```
    renderRow = {(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => <Item data={rowData} onPress={() => this.deleteItem(rowData, sectionID, rowID)}/>}
```

() => creates a function, so when onPress is called it will call this.deleteItem(rowData, sectionID, rowID)

Comment: Thank you so much, it fixed my problem, I didn't know i had to create a method using () => in order to pass arguments.

Comment: No problem, yes you need to do that. Because otherwise deleteItem method wouldn't be called with any arguments. The onPress belongs to your <Item> component, which has nothing to do with the listview.